# Why is output of adb devices inconsistent?

Tags: android

I'm running android emulator on Mac, the output of `adb devices` is different every time I run it,

```
[PWD: ~/Library/Android]
%> adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5564   offline
emulator-5562   offline
emulator-5560   offline
emulator-5554   offline
emulator-5556   device

[PWD: ~/Library/Android]
%> adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-5560   offline
emulator-5556   device
```

What could the problem be?

I already killed the server and restarted it.

Comment: Maybe there are more that one instance of server running ? Check ps -A | grep -i adb

Comment: @Rafal I got only one entry

Comment: @Rafal problem resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally sad story!

I have programs listening on local ports `5551, 5553, 5554, 5555, 5561` etc.

And adb is connecting to these ports which receives unexpected response, resulting in inconsistent output.

Comment: Total unexpected behavior. Make this as accepted answer so other will knot that is correct.